# Java JSepartor in a JList without using nonsense string in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jseparator

I have a JList populating a list of strings

```
String[] values = new String[] {"David Pickwell", "-", "Tico", "-", "Jack Wilshere", "-","Nick Johanson"};
```

I have been using this method for years to add JSeparator to the GUI with a custom ListCellRender. So, it will check if the current string equals to "-", it will render a separator.

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Object> list, Object value,
    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

  ...  

  String str = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
  if (SEPARATOR.equals(str)) { // What I am talking about
    return separator;
  }

  ...

  return this;
}
```

I must say I do not like it. It works but it would take some more work later to check for string to send request to... somewhere else. So, I would like to do:

```
String[] values = new String[] {"David Pickwell", "Tico", "Jack Wilshere", "Nick Johanson"};
```

And after every item, a new separator will be presented.

How could I do it?

Comment: You might get some ideas from [this example](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/jcombobox_items_with_separators) which uses a `JComboBox`

Comment: It is still checking for string, then insert a separator after it.

Comment: Do you want to re-write the `ListUI` or `JList` classes?  Basically you would need some way to either return two different cell renderers based on your needs or supplement the paint process. This is more difficult than it sounds, as you will be modifying the row height and thus any of the mouse hit functionality along the way

Comment: I want to go with JList, but if ListUI could do better, it would be the choice. I'm ok with current work around, but would kill to do it better.

Comment: As already mentions this is not trivial. It also affects keyboard actions with the up/down arrow keys. And postential multi selection of cells. I fail to understand a requirement like this. Why do you need a separator between each item in the list. Maybe just create a custom border that looks like a separator if you want more space between each item in the list.

Comment: By separator, I meant just a thin border underneath each item except the last one. Like we usually do with CSS: `border-bottom: solid 1px #000;`

Answer (score 1):

See these posts.
It seems that others are also using a custom ListCellRender, so maybe that is the way to go. You only need to write that rendered once, though. So if you have written it in the past just parameterize the class and reuse it. I usually found it necessary to build a library of utils when using Swing, or any other GUI toolkit for that matter.

[Java List with line separation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786907/java-list-with-line-separation)
[Adding JSeparator to a DefaultListModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472268/adding-jseparator-to-a-defaultlistmodel)

Comment: It's still using a separator string to check in the string array.

Comment: The problem with these approaches is that (IMHO) you can still select the separator (not tried, but that's what it appears to be doing)

Comment: That's right, the separator is still being selected by the pointer.